# Extracting data from sites php

Tags: php

I have a project am working on. I am using php and mysql as backends. The problem is that i will need to create an online catalog for more than 10k products...each with pdf files as attachment. Now there is no way I could go through them one by one...so am here to ask you the expert for advise. How can I get this data from the suppliers web pages with some having .jsp extensions? Is there a way to extract this huge amount of data without doing it one by one? Thank you and looking forward to your advises.

Comment: It's called screen-scraping, and you shouldn't do it. Ask your supplier if they have an export function or something way of doing a bulk data transfer.

Comment: Don't your suppliers provided some kind of API to talk to? Scraping isn't allowed anyway without consent. Just first ask your suppliers to get an easy way of accessing their product list(s).

Comment: We are trying to do just that...ask them to give us the data, but even they don't have a proper medium to pass this data (as in it is not in format or in one place). They do not mind nonetheless if we copy anything we want from their site.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, contact your supplier for product info. They won't be amused if you scrape and re-publish their website.

> Is there a way to extract this huge amount of data without doing it one by one?

No, there is no other way to do this than visiting every product page. You can't store data that you don't receive.

Answer (score 1):

This is very bad practice -it's slow, your suppliers won't like it I guess and your code gets rubbish whenever the suppliers html code on their site changes.

So the best approach is to use some API if they provided any. If you are really in need of parsing other sites html code you should give [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) a try.

Answer (score 0):

Ask the suppliers if they have a web service or an API that you could interact with.